# (TiledWorldMap) Error: Expected a value of type 'double?', but got one of type 'String'

Tags: flutter, dart, tiled, flame

I am still pretty new to flame, flutter, and dart overall but I am trying to display a tiled world map using the Bonfire plugin which sits on top of flame but whenever I try to run the program it tells me that the value stored in 'TildWorldMap' is of type String and not a double which is correct because I am passing a json file ('tiled/firsttry.json') through the string. I am wondering if there is another way to store the string as a double or if it's just a syntax error that I am not picking up on?

```
import 'package:bonfire/bonfire.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  Flame.device.fullScreen();
  Flame.device.setLandscape();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {


  MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);
  
  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BonfireTiledWidget(
      map: TiledWorldMap('tiled/firsttry.json', forceTileSize: Size(16, 16)),
      lightingColorGame: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.5),
    joystick: Joystick(
      directional: JoystickDirectional(
        isFixed: false,
      )
    ),
      background: BackgroundColorGame(Colors.pinkAccent),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: The `path` argument type is indeed `String` so I don't think that's what's raising the error.

Comment: Can you post the stacktrace?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out by just using a URL instead of the JSON file.